# How to use vuedraggable for nested components that handle data for nested arrays of data in Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, nested, vuex, vuedraggable

I have a list of objects that can each have their own list of children down to any level, and they can be dragged anywhere within the list of object trees.  The data is stored in Vuex and I have the draggables bound to a computed property with a getter and setter (the setter splices in/overwrites the list).

The issue I'm having is when I drag an item anywhere below the first level of the same tree, it disappears, UNLESS I am reordering it amongst siblings on the same level.  It seems to work fine to drag it anywhere else so long as it's not within the same tree.  This makes me suspect it's a mismatch in timing as the events are emitted up the tree structure, but at the same time it's always removed and never appears in the new location whether it's dragged down or up further in the tree.

I'm wondering if this is happening because of emitting an update event up the tree when a nested object changes, vs updating and committing an update to the Vuex store at the top level. I am logging the change correctly in the setter, but it seems to get overwritten immediately after in the data and disappears from the dom.

Is this something others have run into?  Can someone maybe explain the order of operations, maybe I have an issue where the removal update is overriding the addition update?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting around this by checking if the list was reducing in size when the setter was triggered and delaying the cloning and updating of state until after the added element completed its update. Feels like a total hack, so if anyone has thoughts on how to avoid this when using vuedraggable to update nested components in the store, I'd love your insight.